# image analysis question for matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tracking an image in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947761/tracking-an-image-in-matlab)

Hi, I asked a similar question but wasn't quite clear before. I am trying to put a blue or an orange or some other colored circle (more like a donut) around a feature in an image so that I can track it. It should be more like a donut so that I can still view the image... Anyway, I have a multidimensional array and then extract 2D submatrices out of it and plot each one using imagesc(subarray). For all the subarrays there are multiple features that I've located and want to track. Is it possible in Matlab to put a donut/circle around them to do that? How would you do that?